# How to select sub elements with same tag in the same element jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need to parse through a page by jsoup with elements tag `div`, `h3`, `a`, etc. I want to parse through the `div.g` element and get the text of these classes: `a class="l _PMs"` and `a class="_pJs"` to be displayed in `jList`.

As an example taken from Google News, the page looks like this:

```
<div class="g">
    <div class="ts _JGs _KHs _oGs _KGs _jHs">
        <a class="top _xGs _SHs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','dfda','','sdfa','','',event)">
            <img class="th _RGs" src="url" alt="Story image" onload="typeof google==='object'&amp;&amp;google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)">
        </a>
        <div class="_hJs">
            <h3 class="r _gJs">
                <a class="l _PMs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','dfs','','sdfa','','',event)">Report on <em>Example</em> Testing<em>Club</em> ...</a>
            </h3>
            <div class="slp">
                <span class="_OHs _PHs">link</span>
                <span class="_QGs">-</span>
                <span class="f nsa _QHs">date</span>
            </div>
            <div class="st">description</div>
        </div>
        <div class="_sJs card-section">
            <a class="_pJs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','sdf','','sdfa','','',event)" data-href="url">Final review of <em>example's</em> of <em>testing</em>...
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="_cJs"></div>
        <div class="_sJs card-section">
            <a class="_pJs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','dfa','','dfs-d','','',event)" data-href="url">Report on this testing
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="_cJs"></div>
        <div class="_eJs card-section">
            <a class="_pJs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','ad','','dfsaf','','',event)">Test report example
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="_cJs"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="g">
    <div class="ts _JGs _KHs _oGs _KGs _jHs">
        <a class="top _xGs _SHs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','dfda','','sdfa','','',event)">
            <img class="th _RGs" src="url" alt="Story image" onload="typeof google==='object'&amp;&amp;google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)">
        </a>
        <div class="_hJs">
            <h3 class="r _gJs">
                <a class="l _PMs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','dfs','','sdfa','','',event)">Cloud<em>Example</em> Testing<em>1</em> ...</a>
            </h3>
            <div class="slp">
                <span class="_OHs _PHs">link</span>
                <span class="_QGs">-</span>
                <span class="f nsa _QHs">date</span>
            </div>
            <div class="st">description</div>
        </div>
        <div class="_sJs card-section">
            <a class="_pJs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','sdf','','sdfa','','',event)" data-href="url">Final review of this<em>testing</em>...
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="_cJs"></div>
        <div class="_sJs card-section">
            <a class="_pJs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','dfa','','dfs-d','','',event)" data-href="url">Report on this...
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="_cJs"></div>
        <div class="_eJs card-section">
            <a class="_pJs" href="url" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','ad','','dfsaf','','',event)">Example 2...
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="_cJs"></div>
        <div class="tsw _QMs">
            <div class="_jJs card-section">
                <a class="_MHs" href="url" target="_blank" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','sdfs','','dfd','','',event)" data-href="url">
                    <img class="_iJs" id="news-media-image-52779751835836-0" src="url" alt="image1" onload="typeof google==='object'&amp;&amp;google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)">
                    <div class="_RMs">USA TODAY.</div>
                </a>
                <a class="_MHs" href="url" target="_blank" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','sdfsa','','dsfa','','',event)">
                    <img class="_iJs" id="news-media-image-52779751835836-1" src="url" alt="image2" onload="typeof google==='object'&amp;&amp;google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)">
                    <div class="_RMs">image2./div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="_NMs">
                <a class="_OMs" href="url">View all
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code:

```
String input = txtSearch.getText();
input = input.replace(" ", "+");
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + input + "&tbm=nws&source=lnms";
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Chrome").timeout(5000).get();
    Elements e = doc.select("div.g");
    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    e.forEach((e1) -> {
        e1.getElementsByTag("a").forEach(linkElement -> listModel.addElement(linkElement.text()));
    });
    newsList.setModel(listModel);            
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The actual output displayed in `jList` was:

```
Report on Example Testing Club...  
Final review of example's of testing...  
Report on this testing.  
Test report example.
Cloud Example Testing 1.   
Final review of this testing.   
Report on this...   
Example 2...   
USA TODAY.   
image2.   
View all
```

How can I select these classes: `a class="l _PMs"` and `a class="_pJs"` without `a class=_MHs` and `a class=_OMs` being selected, as shown below (in `jList`):

```
Report on Example Testing Club...  
Final review of example's of testing...  
Report on this testing.  
Test report example.
Cloud Example Testing 1.   
Final review of this testing.   
Report on this...   
Example 2...
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this line:

```
Elements e = doc.select("div.g");
```

to

```
Elements e = doc.select("div.g").select("div.a");
```

in loop just check for the text only like:

```
    for(Element element:e)
       {
          yourList.add(e.text());
       }
```

Elements e = doc.select("div.g").select("a"); we will have a list of every  tag element of div.g tag. so now we can traverse now each a tag by for loop and look for text or even attributes..

Comment: i have edited the answer pls try this i am 100% sure it should work....

Comment: it is unable to add a string parameter for the `jList.add()` method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you select all `a` elements inside given `div` and call `.text()` method on this list of all elements - it naturally returns you a concatenated text of all `a` elements.

To make your code work as you expect, you can change:

```
e.forEach((e1) -> {
    listModel.addElement(e1.getElementsByTag("a").text());
});
```

to:

```
e.forEach((e1) -> {
    e1.getElementsByTag("a").forEach(linkElement -> listModel.addElement(linkElement.text()));
});
```

*update*

If you want to select only `a` elements with classes either `l` + `_PMs` or `_pJs`, you can rewrite your code like that:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Chrome").timeout(5000).get();
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
doc.select("div.g a.l._PMs, div.g a._pJs")
        .forEach(element -> listModel.addElement(element.text()));
newsList.setModel(listModel);
```

The selector is: `div.g a.l._PMs, div.g a._pJs` which means to select all elements that fulfill one of these conditions:

- they are inside `a` element that has `l` and `_PMs` class which are inside `div` element with `g` class
- they are inside `a` element that has `_pJs` class which are inside `div` element with `g` class

Comment: can I only select two specific classes: `a class="l _PMs"` and `a class="_pJs"` without selecting the other `a class`? (I have updated the page html, actual output, and the output I want).

Comment: @user7146946 see this gist: https://gist.github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/9eb9f5655083c76d2561781841dc0af5 it works as expected using the code I have provided above

Comment: i am parsing a url, does it affect the selector of the page?

Comment: @user7146946 it shouldn't affect until the page changes :) in my case `google` returns completely different output - there's no `l`, `_PMs` nor `_pJs` classes.

Comment: but for me, `google` returns `l`, `_PMs` and `_pJs` classes.

Comment: @user7146946 Is you google output shown above - in the question? Is it the same?

Comment: @user7146946 I have just rewrote the code in an answer to fit your code, does your code look the same?